# I am trying to increase the cart size using variable "Csize" in Reactjs useEffect and useState

Tags: reactjs, jsx, cart

```js
const [Cart, setCart] = useState([]);
const [Csize, setSize] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
        setSize(Cart.length);
        console.log("updated size", Csize); // Log the updated size directly
}, [Cart]);
    
const handleClick = (item) => {
        // Check if the item is already present in the cart
        const isPresent = Cart.some(cartItem => cartItem.id === item.id);
        if (isPresent) {
            return;
        }
    
        // Update Cart state by adding the new item
        setCart([...Cart, item]);
        console.log(Csize)
    }

<ul>
<Link to="/Cart" className="bikescart"><ShoppingCart color="#ffffff" size={35}/>
<span>{Csize}</span>
</Link>
</ul>
```

This is bikes.jsx file.

And what i am getting in console is everytime i click on add to cart the Csize remains 0.
How to fix this ?

Comment: What's the reason for making size a separate state? Can you not use Cart.length directly, as in:`<span>{Cart.length}</span>`?

Answer (score 0):

actually you are trying to `console.log()` just after you update the state,
and `setState()` function is asynchronous. This means you cannot see updated value of state inside the same function(where you updated the state), so if you want to see updated state of `CSize` just `console.log` outside the `useEffect`.

btw you can directly use length of your `Cart` state without using `useEffect` hook

```html
<Link to="/Cart" className="bikescart"><ShoppingCart color="#ffffff" size={35}/>
<span>{Cart.length}</span>
</Link>
```

Comment: still its the same value thts 0.
this is what i did
```    const [Cart, setCart] = useState([]);
    const [Csize, setSize] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        setSize(Cart.length);
    }, [Cart]);
    
    const handleClick = (item) => {
  
        const isPresent = Cart.some(cartItem => cartItem.id === item.id);
        if (isPresent) {
            return;
        }
        
        
        setCart([...Cart, item]);
        
    }
    console.log("updated size", Csize);```

Comment: please share your code in more details like where are you calling handleClick function because you provided cart state as a dependency in useEffect. Please share brief code.(sorry for late reply i was stuck in some work)

Answer (score 0):

Where are you using `handleClick` function?